# Magento 1.9.0 / M2EPro 6.2.2 / Siteground (???)

Tags: magento, hosting, m2e-pro

Have 3 Magento sites on a shared Siteground Cloud server (2 sites w/dedicated IP's), not sure if any of that information is important BUT here is the problem -

November 11th/12th it appears that Order sync from eBay -> Magento (via M2EPro) stopped working. I have about 6 hours into this challenge today with absolutely no progress other than "Houston we have a problem" ...

Few Additional Pieces of Info;

1) There IS NO order in the Order Synch log since Nov 11th/12th

2) There IS inventory a log for the inventory synch

3) Neither manual or automated (cron) processes are working for order synch

4) I have reviewed the order configuration (ebay->magento) in M2EPro no less than 1/2 dozen times.

Couple of quick questions;

1) Anyone out there running Magento v1.9 w/M2E v6.2+ that IS receiving eBay orders? If so, what host do you use?

2) Anyone else out there running Magento v1.9 w/M2E v6.2+ that IS NOT receiving eBay orders?

My instincts after 6 hours of tracing, error/log hunting tells me that this problem is host related and not software related.

Any/all help is GREATLY appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I run [UnderstandingE.com](http://UnderstandingE.com), earlier this year when researching hosts to suggest to the community, we looked at SiteGround. The thing is that their basic packages don't actually meet the basic requirements for M2EPro.

When M2EPro had the hosting requirements in versions < 6.1 they weren't being met and this will cause issues with order collection and synchronizations.

In the UK we suggest SimpleServers and in the US, SimpleHelix. It is way more expensive than the basic SiteGround packages, but the one thing you cannot skimp on with Magento is quality web hosting.

Oh and do make sure you raise a ticket with M2EPro support, just incase it is not hosting related.

Matt